# I am getting a warning saying I have reached end of non-void function

Tags: c, warnings

I have a function that determines if a year is a leap year and I get a warning but I'm not sure where the warning is. It returns 1 if it is a leap year and 0 if it isn't.

```
int isLeapYear(int yyyy) {
    if (yyyy % 4 == 0) {
        if (yyyy % 100 = 0) {
            if (yyyy % 400 == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
           return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because not all control paths return a value. What does the function return when it is not a leap year (`yyyy` is not divisible by `4`)? The function must end with `return 0;`

Comment: Aside: there is also a typo in the code: `if(yyyy % 100 = 0)` should be `if(yyyy % 100 == 0)`

Comment: After you make a test, do something; avoid doing another test immediately.  `if (yyyy % 4 != 0) return 0; if (yyyy % 100 != 0) return 1; if (yyyy % 400 == 0) return 1; return 0;`

Comment: I figured it out. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out your error and offered alternative ways to code this. Let me offer another. It's an early-return method that keeps the code flatter, shorter, and easier to understand:

```
bool is_leap(int y) {
    if (y % 400 == 0) return true;
    if (y % 100 == 0) return false;
    return y % 4 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `yyyy % 4 == 0` evaluates false, `if (yyyy % 4 == 0) { ... }` body is skipped, you return nothing. Add a `return 0;` to the very end.

Here's a different implementation:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isLeapYear(int const year) {
  if (year % 4) return false;
  if (year % 100) return true;
  return !(year % 400);
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of that sequence of tests (`return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);`) is that the modulo 400 test is always done, though it is very rarely relevant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for the feedback. Would you suggest a different sequence?

Comment: Yes — though I wrote it in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458427/i-am-getting-a-warning-saying-i-have-reached-end-of-non-void-function/60458604?noredirect=1#comment106955807_60458427) to the question.  Of course, that isn't a single expression in the same way, but it deals with the most common case (`yyyy % 4 != 0`) first, and only checks the least common case (now that the year 2000 is firmly in the rearview mirror) last.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler updated the answer in response to your valid criticism.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written this function, it's possible to exit without `return`ing anything.

```
int isLeapYear(int yyyy) {
    if (yyyy % 4 == 0) {
        ...
    }

    <--- Nothing Is Returned Here
}
```

You should doing something like:

```
bool isLeapYear(int yyyy)
{
    bool leapYear = false;

    if (yyyy % 4 == 0) {
        // If Leap Year Set leapYear To true
    }

    return leapYear;
}
```

The benefit of this is, there's only one exit point which makes it possible to set a default `return` value and it's easier to read.